# How to edit an auto response email when a customer opens a case?

Tags: servicecloud

Hoping someone can help me. My company is having a company wide offsite meeting to kickoff the new year. I'd like to edit the email that goes out to customer when they send an email to open a case to my support team, that lets them know we're all out of office, apologies for delays, we'll get back with them soon...yada yada yada.

I cannot find where to do this, and I think I'm going crazy. I know I've done it before....

I've checked the email templates, I only see the web-to-email template, which I updated. I've also looked in Flows, Email-to-case, and case auto response rules. Nothing, no template anywhere.

Help, please!

Answer (score 0):

Just check the **flow on Email Message** once, if you are not using auto response rule etc. & no template is there, then it will be going from **Flow send email action**.

Second you can try to Put the **debug logs for the Email-to-case user from which the case is getting created**, & send a dummy email to any routing service then you can check in the logs that from where the Response email is going to customer.